# How can one write $x^TAx=v^Ty$, where $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $v,y$ are vectors of equal dimension.

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

I wish to express, $x^TAx$ ($x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$) which is a scalar quantity as product of two vectors, i.e, $v^Ty$, where $v$ should only contain elements of $x$ and $y$ should only contain elements of $A$. How can I accomplish that? Is it possible to write this scalar quantity as product of two vectors?

Comment: How about $v=x$ and $y=Ax$?

Comment: No! that wont do, I should have made it clear, y must contain only A and not both A and x

Comment: @Amardeepmishra, what does it mean "$y$ must contain only $A$"? $A$ is a matrix, $y$ is a vector as well as $Ax$.

Comment: @Hasek, $y$ should contain only the elements of $A$, i.e either individual elements, rows or columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in ${\Bbb R}^{n^2}$ with
$$v=(x_1^2,x_1x_2,x_1x_3,\ldots,x_1x_n,x_2x_1,x_2^2,x_2x_3,\ldots,x_2x_n,\ldots,x_n^2)$$
and
$$y=(a_{11},a_{12},a_{13},\ldots,a_{1n},a_{21},a_{22},a_{23},\ldots,a_{2n},\ldots,a_{nn})\ .$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer!